# How to implement our own plugin for report portal

Tags: plugins, reportportal

i want to create my own plugin which i can upload in to report portal

I created a simple plugin using Eclipse IDE (plugin in development) and then exported it as a jar , but when i trying to upload it , it always throw

```
 Error during plugin uploading: 'Plugin version should be specified.'
```

any pointer can help me

Answer (score 1):

ReportPortal plugins must be packaged with additional information in JAR manifest. Refer to [this one as an example](https://github.com/reportportal/plugin-bts-jira/blob/master/build.gradle#L95).

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                "Plugin-Id": "${pluginID}",
                "Plugin-Version": "${project.version}",
                "Plugin-Provider": "<any arbitrary string, e.g. name>",
                "Plugin-Class": "com.epam.reportportal.extension.bugtracking.jira.JiraStrategyPlugin",
                "Plugin-Service": "api"
        )
    }
}
```

Plugins are built and loaded using PF4j framework, so checking [its documentation](https://pf4j.org/) will also be useful